# method() vs Class.method()?

Tags: java, methods

If I am using a method which is a member of the same class I am calling it from, *should* I use the class name or not?

```
public class ThisClass 
{
    public static void example() { }

    public static void example2()
    {
        example();           // or
        ThisClass.example();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You normaly call a method by its name. If it is a regular method (without any special modifier) you call the method of the current instance of your class with "example()" or "this.example()" where "example()" it the short form, cause by default the implementation of your current instance (this) is called.

In case the method is a static one, it is good style to call the method preceded by its declaring class-name

```
ThisClass.example()
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it is unnecessary/extraneous to include the class name when calling a method within the class. When calling a method within the class typically the only time a method should be preceded by anything is when using the super or this keyword.

Comment: The class name on a static method is just as necessary as `this` on an instance method.

Comment: @shmosel I am not sure if that is correct. For example you might have `public static string example(int i)` if you were to call that in the main for i=1, you would simply put `example(1);` in your main method.

Comment: Same with instance methods. Other than a style preference, qualified method names are generally only useful for resolving naming conflicts.